# Writing to an address starting with 0x00 with a Perl script

Tags: bash, perl

Reading the book "Hacking - The Art of Exploitation"; I am following the writer as he changes the execution flow by overflowing the stack and changing the return address of a function. (Specifically, page 135-136) He manages to do this with a Perl script, entering the return address as a command line argument 10 times:

```
$ ./auth_overflow2 $(perl -e 'print "\xbf\x84\x04\x08"x10')
```

where `0x080484bf` is the return address.

I'm trying to do the same, but my return address starts with 0x00. Replacing \x08 with \x00, the null character becomes omitted, therefore address I want to enter is shifted by a byte in the memory map. How can I work around this?

Comment: I don't think this makes sense. bash cannot handle strings with nulls, but even if it did, you wouldn't be able to pass such a string as an argument to a process because `exec` expects null terminated strings and thus it would ignore all the characters after the null.

Comment: @redneb I see... can you think of any alternative ways to fill memory with addresses aligned as dwords? (including addresses starting with 0x00)

Comment: You would have to modify `auth_overflow2` to accept e.g. the hex representation of the address.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Command line-arguments are NUL-terminated strings. Therefore, you can't pass a string containing a NUL. It would be taken to be the end of the string.

```
$ perl -e'system("echo", "abc\x00def", "ghi\x00jkl");'
abc ghi
```

Knowing this, the shell is stripping out the NULs when building the argument.

```
$ perl -e'printf "%v02X\n", $_ for @ARGV' "$( perl -e'print "\xbf\x84\x04\x08" x 5' )"
BF.84.04.08.BF.84.04.08.BF.84.04.08.BF.84.04.08.BF.84.04.08

$ perl -e'printf "%v02X\n", $_ for @ARGV' "$( perl -e'print "\xbf\x84\x04\x00" x 5' )"
BF.84.04.BF.84.04.BF.84.04.BF.84.04.BF.84.04
```

`auth_overflow2` should be modified to take an escaped form of the address, e.g. the address in hex.